# Are people able to hijack compiled libraries with their own implementations?

Tags: c++, security

I have some legacy code that passes around a pointer to an internal data structure that the library uses to manipulate and check state variables. Thinking about refactoring this code, I became curious if creating a bunch of classes that are meant to only be used internally in my library would cause security concerns. Could others link in their own implementations of these methods? Say I have a `Config` class that reads an encrypted license and sets settings correctly. Would it be possible to manipulate this class somehow?

Here's some code I wrote to try initial feasibility

## shared.cpp

```
#include "shared.h"


Config::Config() : max_clients()
{
}

Config::~Config()
{
}

int Config::getMaxClients() const
{
    return max_clients;
}

void Config::setMaxClients(int num)
{
    max_clients = num;
}
```

I compiled this into a shared library with

```
g++ -c shared.cpp -fpic
g++ -shared -o libshared.so shared.o
```

Once compiled we can see what other people can see about our `Config` class in our library.

```
$ nm -C libshared.so
0000000000201030 B __bss_start
0000000000201030 b completed.7696
                 w __cxa_finalize
0000000000000780 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000000810 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000200e20 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000201028 d __dso_handle
0000000000200e58 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000201030 D _edata
0000000000201038 B _end
00000000000008f8 T _fini
0000000000000850 t frame_dummy
0000000000200e18 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000000a50 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000201000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000000910 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000000720 T _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000000007c0 t register_tm_clones
0000000000201030 d __TMC_END__
                 U operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
00000000000008de T Config::setMaxClients(int)
000000000000085a T Config::Config()
000000000000085a T Config::Config()
00000000000008a0 T Config::~Config()
0000000000000882 T Config::~Config()
0000000000000882 T Config::~Config()
00000000000008cc T Config::getMaxClients() const
0000000000200e48 V typeinfo for Config
0000000000000908 V typeinfo name for Config
0000000000200e28 V vtable for Config
                 U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info
```

There's probably a lot more analysis I don't know about here.

## mal.cpp

With this information we could guess a bit about return types on `setMaxClients` and create our own implementation.

```
#include <iostream>

class Config {
public:
    Config() {}
    void setMaxClients(int num);
};

void Config::setMaxClients(int num)
{
    std::cout << "do something bad" << std::endl;
}
```

I compiled this file with

```
g++ -c mal.cpp -fpic
g++ -shared -o libmal.so mal.o
```

## main.cpp

```
class Config {
public:
    Config();
    virtual ~Config();
    int getMaxClients();
    void setMaxClients(int num);
};

int main()
{
    Config config;
    config.setMaxClients(4);

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, I compiled `main.cpp` with linking my `mal` library first then `shared` like so

```
g++ main.cpp -lmal -lshared
```

This produced a binary which when run I get

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
do something bad
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
[1]    7842 abort (core dumped)  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out
```

Yes it crashed but I'm not more experienced to know where to go next. Is this not a security concern because you wouldn't actually be able to change any of the classes fields since you don't know the member variables? Or is there a concern here that requires best practices in C++?

Comment: If an attacker is able to run arbitrary code on your machine, then hijacking this library is the least of your worries.

Comment: This code won't be run on my machine. This code with be run on client's machines. I'm wondering if there is a concern with keeping some features disabled or limited on the client's side. Is there a possibility for clients to mess with my library's implementation at all?

Comment: If you have access to the binary and the right skills, then it's possible to reverse engineer it and modify it, yes. Just think about how quickly copy protection on games get bypassed.

Comment: People can screw with your code on their machines no matter how you refactor it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replacement class should ideally be the same size as the original class. The config in main.cpp has a virtual dtor, whereas the one in mal.cpp does not. This will cause the latter to be 8bytes larger (assuming 64bit OS), and will invariably lead to a problem on destruction of the class.
If this is a real concern, a simple next step is to perform a checksum on the dll, and validate that at runtime (quit if checksum does not match). It wont help a great deal for someone who really cares though. If you know enough about asm, you can usually patch a binary exe with some no-ops until your check returns true.